# Farmer needs algorithm for looping through self-referencing animal table

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, database-design

**The problem:** There's a ton of animals on a farm.  Every animal can have any number of animal friends, except for the anti-social animals--they don't have friends that *belong* to them, but they belong to other normal animals as friends.  Each animal is exactly as happy as it's least happiest animal friend, except for the anti-social animals of course.  The anti-social animals happiness' levels can be anything.

One morning all the animals wake up and find some of the anti-social animals mood's have changed.  How does the farmer figure out the happiness of each animal?

Here's as far as the ranch hands got (they didn't go to farmer school):

[image: one-to-many self-referencing table]

```
DataTable animals = Select_All_Animals();
foreach (DataRow animal in animals.Rows)
{
    int worstMood = 10; //Super Happy!
    DataTable friendRecords = Select_Comp_Animal_AnimalFriend((int)animal["AnimalID"]);
    foreach (DataRow friend in friendRecords.Rows)
    {
        DataTable animalFriends = Select_AnimalFriend((int)friend["AnimalID_Friend"]);
        foreach (DataRow animalFriend in animalFriends.Rows)
        {
            int animalMood = Get_Animal_Mood((int)animalFriend["Mood"]);
            if (animalMood < worstMood)
            {
                worstMood = animalMood;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this will not work because the animal table does not sequentially follow the animal friend hierarchies that have formed.  Animals can make friends with each other at any time!  So Animal(1) might have Animal(4000) as a friend.  Animal(1) will not show an accurate mood because it will check Animal(4000)'s mood before Animal(4000)'s mood has been updated itself.  And new animals are being dropped off everyday.  I figure the solution might a common algorithm design, but I haven't been able to find it.  I don't believe I have the correct terminology to accurately search for it.

Thanks a bunch and sorry if this has already been answered!

**Added:**

Here's a ghetto Paint chart of possible relationships:

[image: like an acyclic graph]

The anti-social animals are at the bottom level and have no friends belonging to them.  The normal animals are everywhere else above.  There is no exact structure to the normal animal friendships, except (as Sebastian pointed out) there can't be a closed loop (if designed correctly).

There will be hundred's of thousands of animals added weekly and processing speed is a critical element.

Comment: A few questions :
- has the friendship relationship the properties one would expect to have such as symmetry ?
- your definition of happiness is a bit bury : is it a property that holds at anytime ? do we have initial value for the happiness of the different animals ? 
If I understand everything properly, if we take an animal, and its friends, and the friends of its friends, etc until we can't take anymore friends, every animal has exactly the same level of happiness ? Then, if we update the happiness of one, we update it for everyone in the group ?

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see the rest of your comment.  Yes, you are correct.  All the normal animals basically have a default happiness state until the first morning an anti-social animal wakes up with a random happiness state.

Comment: 1) If A is friend with B, is B friend with A ?
2) If yes, if we take an animal and its friends and their friends, etc, do you agree that they should all have the same level of happiness ? (Which is the minimum of the happiness of the different animals)

Comment: 1) No.  It is a one way friendship. 2) An animal should always have equal to or lower level of happiness than their friends, except for the anti-social ones, because they don't **have** friends... if that makes sense.  It's a parent child relationship in a way.

Comment: Ok, all my question were based on the assumptions that the friendship would be two ways. I can see that you did get nice answers already :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by grabbing all the antisocial animals and ordering them from least happy to most happy. Initialise the happiness of all the social animals to the maximum (this makes everything easier since you don't have to detect when a previously unhappy animal gets happier). Then just iterate over the list and propagate the happiness levels up the friendship chains:

```
void UpdateFarm()
{
    // Start with a list of antisocial animals from least to most happy.
    var antisocialAnimals = GetAntisocialAnimals().OrderBy(x => x.Happiness);

    // Initialise the social animals to the global maximum. Note the
    // global maximum is the happiest antisocial animal. This is done to
    // avoid the case where an antisocial animal's happiness has increased,
    // so some of the social animals are too unhappy.
    var maxHappiness = antisocialAnimals.Last().Happiness;
    var socialAnimals = GetSocialAnimals();
    foreach (var socialAnimal in socialAnimals)
        socialAnimal.Happiness = maxHappiness;

    // Now iterate from least to most happy, propagating up the friend chain.
    foreach (var antisocialAnimal in antisocialAnimals)
        UpdateFriends(antisocialAnimal);
}

// To propagate a happiness change, we just find all friends with a higher
// happiness and then lower them, then find their friends and so on.
void UpdateFriends(Animal animal)
{
    var friends = GetFriends(animal); // Friends with this animal, not friends of.

    foreach (var friend in friends.Where(x => x.Happiness > animal.Happiness))
    {
        friend.Happiness = animal.Happiness;

        // Since this friend's happiness has changed, we now need to update
        // its friends too.
        UpdateFriends(friend);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coding this out.  Looks pretty optimized.  Very nice.  I'm stuck in .net 2.0 for this thing but implementing the linq logic with other functions shouldn't be a problem i assume, though maybe not as fast or pretty. bravo.

Comment: @bmewburn I don't see how either of those things pose a problem. Can you explain why you think they do? When an animal has multiple chains to antisocial animals, it will be set to the lowest happiness and then ignored by the subsequent ones, and the algorithm will only go around a cycle once and then stop. In both cases the relevant check is `Where(x => x.Happiness > animal.Happiness)` (which will be false).

Comment: @verdesmarald, yep, you're correct, I take it back. And because you have to visit every node to set the mood then I guess you cant do better than O(n).

Answer (score 4):

Nice question. So, if i understand correctly you basically have directed graph with cycles. You can think of every animal as a node (vertex) that has outgoing edge to animal on which it mood depends, and incoming edges from animals which mood it influences. Obviously anti-social animals will have incoming edges only.

If you think about it this way you will notice two things

1) You can devise a iterative algorithm that will sweep trough all animals, checking for each animal if it has any outgoing edges only to anit-social or already processed animal, if yes, we compute mood of the animal, and mark it as processed. If not, we just skip it for this iteration.

2) Because you can have cycles in your graph, this algorithm will not always finish. That is you may have Animal A depending on B, B depending on C and C depending on A. If you have simple logic, as in your case, that the lowest mood wins, you could probably detect and resolve those cycles by assigning to all animals in the cycle - in this case A,B,C lowest common mood.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, awesome idea.  That might work.  The relationship between the animals is such that it maintains a hierarchical tree view in a way (i'm terrible at the terminology here).  The friendships either go down the chain or across, but never back up.

Comment: Great. that way you'll get acyclic graph - which means that after finite number of iterations you will have all your animals processed (that is having updated mood assigned).

Comment: wow.  I think you landed it.  I'm thinking through your logic and it seems sound.  Acyclic graph also looks to be exactly the behavior i'm looking at.  Very impressed.

Comment: Thanks - using graph theory makes it easier too. If your function to calculate mood changes, for example if you later decide to base mood as an average of friend animals, or some other more complex calcualtion, then you need to make change only in one place.

Answer (score 2):

There are other, more suitable answers already, but I'll throw this out there as an interesting thought experiment - it'd be hairy as hell to do in a database, as well as being woefully inefficient:

The happiness level of any animal is a relationship of current happiness, "pulled" or "pushed" by the animals it is friends with.

Therefore, a change in one animal's happiness level would cause a wave of adjustments that would potentially affect all the animals.

Picture the "friendship graph" as a bunch of boxes connected to other boxes via springs. The boxes obviously represent animals, the springs the "effect" on neighboring animals.

Pull one box, and a wave of motion expands from the moved box; this in turn will eventually cause a reverse ripple effect -I make you happier, so in turn you will eventually over time make me happier (or sadder) from the effect of that relationship.

"But it'll keep adjusting itself forever without settling into a steady state!" Enter a "friction" term, which counteracts tiny movements (say under some threshold value, the "pull" can't overcome the inertia of sadness/happiness).

Sounds a lot like flocking behavior of Boids by Craig whats-his-name. (reference needed) - again, I must stress this is decidedly non-optimal for what you're trying to do, but I always like looking at a problem from multiple angles.

Comment: i'll talk to the accounting department, see if we can get this implemented ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like homework but I'll have a crack, I took an idea or two from the other guys:

```
public void MoodCalculator()
{

 /** Reasoning:
 * 
 * The unidirectional cyclic graph can be also expressed as multiple friend 
 * trees where
 * anti-social animal is the root node of a friend tree. Because a social animal's
 * mood is that of its lowest mood friend this means that regardless of the 
 * tree depth of an animal
 * it's mood is that of the mood of the lowest mood antisocial animal 
 * who's tree it is a member of.  
 * 
 * */

  SortedList<int, List<Animal>> moodGroups = new SortedList<int, List<Animal>>();

  HashSet<Animal> allAnimals = new HashSet<Animal>();

  //get all antisocial animals and group according to mood
  //work from low to high mood
  forach(Animal a in GetAllAntiSocialAnimalsFromDb()) 
  {
     if(!moodGroups.ContainsKey(a.Mood)) moodGroups.Add(a.Mood, new List<Animal>());
     moodGroups[a.Mood].Add(a);
  }

  foreach(var item in moodGroups)
  {
     //add our root antisocial animals to master group
     foreach(Animal a in item.Value) allAnimals.Add(a);

     //recurse over tree starting at antisocial animal roots
     TreeRecurse(item.Value, allAnimals, item.Key);
  }


 }

 public void TreeRecurse(List<Animal> children, List<Animal> allAnimals, int mood)
 {
    //can look for list as we are just grouping everything and don't care about tree 
    //structure
    //db call should only get unique/distinct animals
    List<Animal> parentAnimals = GetParentAnimalsOfChildAnimalListFromDb(children);
    //remove animals from from parents if they are already in the allAnimal set
    //working from low mood to high we can ignore animals that have appeared in a 
    //lower mood tree
    parentAnimals.RemoveAll(a => allAnimals.Contains(a));
    //add animals to allAnimals and set mood
    foreach (Animal a in parentAnimals)
    {
       a.Mood = mood;
       allAnimals.Add(a);
    }
    //end recurse
    if (parentAnimals.Count == 0) return;
    //recurse
    else TreeRecurse(parentAnimals, allAnimals, mood);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem.  If I understand it correctly, each animal's happiness is the MIN of the happiness of all if it's one-way friends (inbound).

If that's so, then the challenge is that each of the animal's friends' happiness is subject to THEIR friends and so on so where to start.

Here's what I think at first glance...

Since new animals show up every day, you need to start fresh every day and you need to start with the animal(s) with the lowest starting happiness.  It's easy enough to find those and then propogate that happiness out to all the animals they are friends to, adjusting those levels of happiness down accordingly.  Then take all the adjusted animals and repeat until no more animals are adjusted.  Once that happiness level is fully propogated, move to the next-highest happiness level and repeat until the highest remaining level of happiness is handled.

One interesting point to this is that it doesn't matter which animals, if any, are anti-social.  They are just animals with no influencing inputs and therefore won't be adjusted by this process.

I think that will get you where you want to be and it shouldn't be difficult at all to code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

- If an antisocial-animal's mood is the absolute lowest, then all of its friends and friends-of-friends will inherit its overridingly-bad mood.
- If an antisocial-animal's mood is the second-absolute lowest, then all of its friends and friends-of-friends will inherit its mood, only if they aren't already a friend/friend-of-friend of the absolute-lowest-mood animal
- ...

This therefore suggests the following algorithm:

To start things off you set the social-animal moods to MAX_MOOD and you loop through the antisocial-animals in order of increasing mood and recursively update the mood of all of its friend and friends-of-friends. If during the recursion you don't update a mood, then you can stop recursing, and that's why you would loop through in order of increasing mood: to 'block' as much future recursion as possible.

This is similar to Sebastian K's "marking as processed" although you don't need to keep a separate list of what has been processed, because the mood itself contains this information. This will also implement his solution the the cycle problem, as recursion will traverse the cycle once and stop.